# Windows (NetBios) сеть

Tags: windows, wins, netbios, dhcp

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужно поставить DHCP и WINS на наш WinServer 2003. И после этого сетевое окружение стало глючить. То оно показывает все машины, то ни одной. В сети много инфы про настройки wins для dhcp, но, дело в том, что я уже отключил WINS и убрал в DHCP все настройки для WINS, а сеть продолжает так же глючить. Че делать? Какая информация понадобится?

Comment: Я понимаю, что Windows сети это широкий вопрос, но подскажите хоть, в какую сторону копать? Может есть хорошие книги по Вин Серверам?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите лекции на сайте проекта [ИНТУИТ](http://www.intuit.ru/department/network/netmsserver2003/). Там достаточно подробно описана именно сетевая инфраструктура Windows Server. Также рекомендую посмотреть в сторону [библиотеки TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc706993(WS.10).aspx). И обратите внимание на то, какие службы у Вас работают или не работают, попробуйте поиграться с ними (в основном дело именно в службах).

Comment: Спасибо и на том!